# Identity in Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If the equality

$$\left(A \cup B\right) \cap C = A \cup \left(B \cap C\right)$$

is not identically true, I need to find the case(s) in which it is true.

(i) Is it reasonable to use a typical Venn diagram of three overlapping circles to reason this out?

(ii) I reached the conclusion that the statement is true when $A\setminus C = \emptyset$ , since that is the case when the areas overlap in the diagram from (i). Is this correct?

Comment: Try $C=A\cup B$. The idea is write $C =f(A,B)$.

Comment: But isn't that just a different way of saying the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i) Drawing a Venn diagram is an excellent way and makes the answer clear.

lhs = $(A\cap C)\cup(B\cap C)$. Now compare that with the rhs = $A\cap(B\cup C)$.

$A$ is the disjoint union of $A\cap C$ and $A\setminus C$, so they are the same iff $A\setminus C\subseteq (B\cap C)$. But every point of $B\cap C$ is in $C$, whereas no points of $A\setminus C$ are in $C$, so a necessary and sufficient condition is $A\setminus C=\emptyset$.

Comment: Thanks. One question: Is this case the only case where this is true?

Comment: @sandbag66: That's what “necessary condition” means.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

RHS:

$A\cup (B \cap C)=$

$(A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C)$(Distributive law).

Compare to LHS, we get:

$A\cup C= C$ (why?)

$\iff$ $A\subset C$  $\iff $ $A$ \ $C=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what you mean by $A$ \ $C$, but... if $A \subseteq C$, then $(A \cup B) \cap C = A \cup (B \cap C)$